# When to use UIViewController Containment? (delegation overload)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

[image]

I have a view that contains a mapview and a tableview, similar to how to the facebook nearby places screen looks in the facebook app looks.

I put the screen together using interface builder.  I have outlets to the tableview and map. And, I set the UIViewController that controls the main view to be the delegate for both the mapview and table view.   Everything works perfectly.

However, this main UIViewController is now pretty messy because it has to respond to methods on behalf of it's own view, the mkmapview and the uitableview.  However, data is somewhat shared between the map and the table view.

I am wondering if this is where UIViewController containment comes in?  Or, if I should should just make custom objects to act as delegates for those two views.  I am looking for the correct design pattern to use in modern iOS.  A few years ago just mashing it all into the same controller would be the way to go.  Maybe it still is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your ideas are good thoughts, but...

Controller containment is typically used for more navigation related purposes, like a UINavigationController.

Custom objects that do some of the delegate/datasource work, that's a good thought too, but a little clumsy to the extent that they share data with the view controller and each other.  This might be a good solution especially if other view controllers will need the same delegate/datasource behavior.

A third alternative, and probably the best of the three, is to create class extensions of the view controller ([see apple doc here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)).  These can be thought of as parts of your class in different files.

Comment: First, that cleared up what containment is about and makes sense.  The third option is good idea and results with having more focused files.  I'm just not sure I want to have one class broken up over multiple files.  I'm going to see what else comes in, but so far this answer has been quite helpful.